# Doulos SIL Cipher Font not working the way it's supposed to be

Tags: c#, unicode, label

i read the [Documentation](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=CipherMusic) about the font [Doulos SIL Chipher](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=CipherMusic) and then i try it but it not working like the doc. said

[image]

here is my code

```
string stringUnicode = "\u1D177\u266F\u0031\u0332\u0307\u002D\u0333\u0036\u0333\u0323\u1D178";

label.Text = stringUnicode;
```